# Numpy Array: First occurence of N consecutive values smaller than threshold

Tags: python, numpy

I have a one-dimensional `numpy` array - for example,

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 2, 4, 10])
```

I would like to obtain the index of the first number for which the N subsequent values are below a certain value x.

In this case, for `N=3` and `x=3`, I would search for the first number for which the three entries following it were all less than three. This would be `a[4]`.

This can easily be implemented by simply iterating through all the values via a `for` loop, but I was wondering if there any cleaner and more efficient ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: loop backwards and check if the sum of the three satisfies the condition?

Comment: @bbd108 doing it backwards has the disadvantage that you have to exhaust the list to be sure; its cannot short-circuit.

Comment: yeah it is just always O(n).

Comment: @Henry Shackleton Since you mentioned input as array, edited the sample to reflect the same.

Comment: This is actually a very interesting probelm. The best algorithm I can think of, for the example given, would skip entries 4 and 5, since while checking entry 1, it met a 7 at position 3.. So it would solve this in the 2nd iteration, not the 4th.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Approach #1 :**

Here's a vectorized NumPy way -

```
def start_valid_island(a, thresh, window_size):
    m = a<thresh
    me = np.r_[False,m,False]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(me[:-1]!=me[1:])
    lens = idx[1::2]-idx[::2]
    return idx[::2][(lens >= window_size).argmax()]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [44]: a
Out[44]: array([ 1,  4,  5,  7,  1,  2,  2,  4, 10])

In [45]: start_valid_island(a, thresh=3, window_size=3)
Out[45]: 4

In [46]: a[:3] = 1

In [47]: start_valid_island(a, thresh=3, window_size=3)
Out[47]: 0
```

**Approach #2 :**

With [`SciPy's binary-erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

def start_valid_island_v2(a, thresh, window_size):
    m = a<thresh
    k = np.ones(window_size,dtype=bool)
    return binary_erosion(m,k,origin=-(window_size//2)).argmax()
```

**Approach #3 :**

To complete the *set*, here's a loopy one based on short-ciruiting and using the efficiency of `numba` -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def start_valid_island_v3(a, thresh, window_size):
    n = len(a)
    out = None
    for i in range(n-window_size+1):
        found = True
        for j in range(window_size):
            if a[i+j]>=thresh:
                found = False
                break
        if found:
            out = i
            break
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [142]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000000))

In [145]: %timeit start_valid_island(a, thresh=3, window_size=3)
1 loop, best of 3: 810 ms per loop

In [146]: %timeit start_valid_island_v2(a, thresh=3, window_size=3)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.27 s per loop

In [147]: %timeit start_valid_island_v3(a, thresh=3, window_size=3)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 608 ns per loop
```

Comment: Mind Approach #1's ```window_size``` parameter. ```a[5] = 4``` with ```start_valid_island(a, thresh=3, window_size=3)``` gives ```0```. In other words, when there's no islands meeting ```window_size```, the function will just return the first index meeting ```threshold```. Beware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, will return `None` if no number matches the condition:

```
def func(a, n, x):
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
        nextN = a[i+1:i+n+1]
        if len(nextN) < n:
            return None
        elif all([j < x for j in nextN]):
            return e
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, this is how to do it in *vanilla-python*.

```
a = [1,4,5,7,1,2,2,4,10]

res = next(i for i in range(len(a)-3) if all(j<3 for j in a[i:i+3]))
print(res)  # 4
```

Probably most `Numpy` solutions are going to be faster though.

Also note that the above will throw `StopIteration` if no solution can be found, so consider wrapping it up in a `try`-block.